# How do i store the value of appended list in a for loop, outside the for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter

this a tkinter gui to input prices. It will add the prices to the empty list and tell the user the the sum of the list. but now i want to use the data outside of the for loop but whatever version of the list i can think of using it always shows up as an empty list.

```
EXTRAS = []
```

```
def add():
    for x in range(1):
        EXTRAS.append(user_input1g.get())
        EXTRAS_int = [float(x) for x in EXTRAS]
        entry_label1g.config(text=str(sum(EXTRAS_int)))
        user_input1g.delete(0, 10)
        


# Entry
user_input1g = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
user_input1g.grid(row=5, column=1)
# Add button
add_button1g = tk.Button(window, text="Add", command=add)
add_button1g.grid(row=5, column=2)
# Empty label
entry_label1g = tk.Label(window, text="")
entry_label1g.grid(row=5, column=4, pady=10)
# $
entry_label2g = tk.Label(window, text="$")
entry_label2g.grid(row=5, column=3, pady=10)
# Description
entry_label3g = tk.Label(window, text="EXTRAS")
entry_label3g.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10)`
```

i tried

- `print(EXTRAS)` `outcome = []`
- `print(ETRRAS_int)` but that doesn't exist outside the loop.

```
def add():
    for x in range(1):
        EXTRAS.append(user_input1g.get())
        EXTRAS_int = [float(x) for x in EXTRAS]
        entry_label1g.config(text=str(sum(EXTRAS_int)))
        user_input1g.delete(0, 10)
        EXTRAS_SUM = sum(EXTRAS_int)

print(EXTRAS_SUM) but that doesnt work either.
```

Comment: Fair enough thanks for the document i didnt know that was a thing. i have about 7 lists were the user can add their expenses. i want to show the total off all the expense lists added up together. Then i have one list for their income. i want to subtract the total off all expenses from the income list.

Comment: Yeah every list has its own button and yes thats what i want. Sorry about the formulation of the question im still very new to all of this

Comment: That makes this the textbook definition of a XY problem.  Post the actual code for your program or create a [example] if none of the answers so far have worked for you

Comment: alright ill think it over again

Comment: What the point of using for loop if the for loop has only one iteration?

Comment: Well apparently nothing. if just been trying to coming stuff i learned in tutorials to make something for myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title("Test Window")
window.geometry('300x300')

EXTRAS = []
EXTRAS_SUM = 0

def add():
    global EXTRAS_SUM
    EXTRAS.append(float(user_input1g.get()))   
    entry_label1g.config(text=str(sum(EXTRAS)))
    user_input1g.delete(0, 10)
    EXTRAS_SUM = sum(EXTRAS)


# Entry
user_input1g = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
user_input1g.grid(row=5, column=1)
# Add button
add_button1g = tk.Button(window, text="Add", command=add)
add_button1g.grid(row=5, column=2)
# Empty label
entry_label1g = tk.Label(window, text="")
entry_label1g.grid(row=5, column=4, pady=10)
# $
entry_label2g = tk.Label(window, text="$")
entry_label2g.grid(row=5, column=3, pady=10)
# Description
entry_label3g = tk.Label(window, text="EXTRAS")
entry_label3g.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
print(EXTRAS)       #output: [12.0, 2.0, 5.5]
print(EXTRAS_SUM)   #output: 19.5
```

Comment: For a better answer, you need to explain what you have changed to address OP problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title("Test Window")
window.geometry('300x300')

EXTRAS = []

def add():
    for x in range(1):
        EXTRAS.append(float(user_input1g.get()))
        entry_label1g.config(text=str(sum(EXTRAS)))
        user_input1g.delete(0, 10)
        


# Entry
user_input1g = tk.Entry(window, width=5)
user_input1g.grid(row=5, column=1)
# Add button
add_button1g = tk.Button(window, text="Add", command=add)
add_button1g.grid(row=5, column=2)
# Empty label
entry_label1g = tk.Label(window, text="")
entry_label1g.grid(row=5, column=4, pady=10)
# $
entry_label2g = tk.Label(window, text="$")
entry_label2g.grid(row=5, column=3, pady=10)
# Description
entry_label3g = tk.Label(window, text="EXTRAS")
entry_label3g.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
print(EXTRAS)
```

Comment: This also doesnt give me the value of the list. outside the for loop

Answer (score -1):

you can use the functions beginning with the keyword `global`.
In this case, it references the value of use **EXTRAS** and **EXTRAS_int** so it changes their values also outside the function.

It looks as follows:

```py
def add():
    global EXTRAS_int
    global EXTRAS
    for x in range(1):
        EXTRAS.append(user_input1g.get())
        EXTRAS_int = [float(x) for x in EXTRAS]
        entry_label1g.config(text=str(sum(EXTRAS_int)))
        user_input1g.delete(0, 10)
```

Try to call another function that prints your lists, it should print the updated values. Good luck :)